# Angular2 RC5 forces one to move component imports to NgModule declaration - Why?

Tags: angular

It seems any `import` statement you previously made in your Components that were declared in the `directives`, `pipes` and `providers` part of the `@Component()` now **must** be moved to the `@ngModule` declaration.

**Why is this?**

I understand that it's to lessen boilerplate in the Components but this only makes sense for declarations that are **reused** multiple times in the application.

For directives, components, pipes or providers that are only used in one single component, it seems very unnecessary and will lead to heavy bloating of the `@ngModules` file.

In the link below, in the final step5 it states:

> For RC5, you can leave your components, directives and pipes in the
> directives and pipes properties of your @Component metadata. In fact,
> we automatically hoist (add) them to the NgModule to which they
> belong.
>
> **This option is temporary for backward compatibility. It will be
> removed in the final release of Angular 2.0.**
>
> Get ahead of the game and start moving your component directives and
> pipes into module declarations as soon as possible. We intend to
> delete all deprecated class, methods, and properties in the next RC.

**Source**: [RC4 to RC5 migration](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Update 2

As I do more work with `NgModule` myself, I find that the real answer to this is what the docs call [Feature Modules](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#feature-modules).

This is the idea that for subareas of the application that have declarations, etc. you are supposed to put each area into a sub-module, AKA feature module.

So, your components that have directives only used in them, and not used application wide, will not turn into a component + a module, where the module is about declarations and providers, and the component is just doing normal component work.

I'm not sure whether I like this for decorators, but I definitely like it for providers for example. Now it's easy to know where to look for providers of services when debugging service lifetime issues if you run into those.

One more thing I'm still not sure whether I like or not, is that feature modules do not inherit module imports from parent modules. This means you have to import `BrowserModule`, `HttpModule`, and `FormsModule` in every single feature module. I understand why (to be self-contained), but I hate the verbosity.

That said, you can wrap all common imports into a shared module, and now you have one thing only to import into your feature modules. That's the usage pattern suggested by ng2-translate for example, look [here](https://github.com/ocombe/ng2-translate#usage) after "If you have multiple NgModules".

### Update 1

The particular section of the design doc that answers this question is the section titled **Deprecation** (and sub-section **Why** inside it. Here's a [direct link to that section](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1isijHlib4fnukj-UxX5X1eWdUar6UkiGKPDFlOuNy1U/pub#h.5fritim1x5kz).

### Original Answer

The idea is that the AoT (Ahead of Time) compiler can take a module and compile all its dependencies in one go. It's also that within the same module, you don't have to redefine them in your component context repetitively.

Also the router is then able to use modules as boundaries for lazy-loading, since it can lazy load a module knowing the module declaration contains all its dependencies.

If you read the [announcement](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/08/angular-2-rc5-ngmodules-lazy-loading.html) and [design document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1isijHlib4fnukj-UxX5X1eWdUar6UkiGKPDFlOuNy1U/pub) you'll get the idea better.

Comment: I understand the reasoning but I still question it. A lot of times I create a ComponentX that is ONLY used inside ComponentY and nowhere else. And I have a boat load of these single-use-components. Won't it bloat the @ngModule declaration when I have to list every single Component in my app there? Also structurally, I think it makes more sense to keep CompX declared/imported only inside CompY since it's not used anywhere else in the module.

Comment: They probably expect you to use Modules for these (so even in 1 route you'd have child `NgModule`s. I completely agree with you though, which makes the point an opinion based matter better suited for Github issues or [Gitter Angular2 chat](https://gitter.im/angular/angular) than StackOverflow. For the record I personally think Angular 2 is becoming even more verbose, which is my main (only?) complaint against it.

Comment: I added more thoughts to the answer now that I got to migration an existing app to using `NgModule`.